# How to fix `previous closure requires unique access` error?

Tags: rust

I have the following code:

```
use scopeguard::{guard, ScopeGuard}; // 1.1.0

struct S; // comes from a crate, non-clonable

impl S {
    fn free(&mut self, _: u32) {}
}

fn bar(_: &mut S) -> Result<(), ()> {
    Err(())
}

fn test(s: &mut S) -> Result<u32, ()> {
    let i = 10u32; // assuming this is an object from some crate, not just normal u32

    let sg = guard(i, |i| {
        s.free(i); // guarding the object. If something goes wrong the object should be freed.
    });
    
    let _ = bar(s)?; // assuming this can fail and the previously created object `i` should be freed before the function returns

    // here goes a lot of similar procedures:
    //   - first, create an object
    //   - second, wrap it in a guard closure
    // now if any of the procedures fail, all previously created objects will be freed
    
    Ok(ScopeGuard::into_inner(sg))
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = S {};

    let _ = test(&mut s);
}
```

Which fails with the compilation error message:

```
error[E0501]: cannot borrow `*s` as mutable because previous closure requires unique access
  --> src/lib.rs:20:17
   |
16 |     let sg = guard(i, |i| {
   |                       --- closure construction occurs here
17 |         s.free(i); // guarding the object. Is something goes wrong the object should be freed.
   |         - first borrow occurs due to use of `*s` in closure
...
20 |     let _ = bar(s)?; // assuming this can fail and the previoously created object `i` should be freed before the function returns
   |                 ^ second borrow occurs here
21 | 
22 |     Ok(ScopeGuard::into_inner(sg))
   |                               -- first borrow later used here
```

I need to create a lot of objects where each one depends on another or on some other input parameters. I used `scopeguard` crate, but that's not important here - in the end, a closure is created which captures its environment and doesn't let me use the captured object.

As I understand, the `s` object is a mutable reference and the first borrow overlaps with the second borrow which is not allowed in Rust. I'm searching for a workaround or a completely different idiomatic way to solve my task.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=previous+closure+requires+unique+access

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I know how to use search. Your link doesn't answer the question of how to solve my particular task idiomatically.

Comment: It seems kind of wrong that the scope guard needs mutable access to the unrelated variable `s`. What is `s`, and why does the scope guard need to mutate it?

Comment: @SvenMarnach In my case `s` is [vulkan::Allocator](https://docs.rs/gpu-allocator/0.9.0/gpu_allocator/vulkan/struct.Allocator.html). The allocator is needed to allocate/free vulkan memory, that's why it's a mutable reference. The scopeguard takes a closure of type `FnOnce` which captures `s`.

Comment: Given the constraints, I'd go with the obvious solution, `RefCell`. That way the guard only retains a shared reference to the cell and you can keep using it. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=82ec99e9bf77e33d53d002eba3e4298e

Comment: @user4815162342 Note that `s.borrow_mut()` returns a `RefMut<'_, &mut S>`, so you only need to dereference in the call to `bar()` to get an `&mut S`, i.e. you don't need the `&mut` in that call. Including it works, too, since the compiler will auto-dereference the `&mut &mut S` back to a `&mut S`, but it's kind of confusing to rely on that.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks. I actually hoped that `bar(s.borrow_mut())` would just work, but it doesn't, so I assumed that I need to perform a reborrow (i.e. deref followed by ref). Even after working in Rust for years I occasionally find `Deref` and `DerefMut` confusing, expecting them to do the opposite of what they actually do. (E.g. I'd expect a **de**-ref of a type that logically holds `&mut T` to return a `T`, i.e. to de-reference the reference.)

Comment: @user4815162342 The issue here is that the type wrapped inside the `RefCell` is `&mut S`, which is somewhat unusual – it's more common to wrap owned values in `RefCell`.

Comment: @user4815162342 Could you turn your comment to an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @SvenMarnach Right. `deref_mut()` will indeed return `&mut &mut S`, but `*x` is equivalent to `*x.deref_mut()` (note the `*`), so it will provide the needed `&mut S`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the constraints, I'd go with the obvious solution, a [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html). It has a bad rap of being overused, but is actually designed for scenarios like this one. Using `RefCell` without an `Rc` is a good sign of doing it right.

`RefCell` allows the guard to capture the value by shared reference, which leaves it available for your use:

```
fn test(s: &mut S) -> Result<u32, ()> {
    let i = 10u32;
    let s = RefCell::new(s);

    let sg = guard(i, |i| {
        s.borrow_mut().free(i);
    });

    let _ = bar(*s.borrow_mut())?;

    Ok(ScopeGuard::into_inner(sg))
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=18f5157ec69586711399ed3742aa3a41)